# OracleDependency supported query types

Tags: c#, oracle

i have developed a windows service that uses the database chance notification feature.

it works fine when i use the query to monitor a table.

if my query points to a view, i got this error message:

```
Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x0000751F): ORA-29983: Unsupported query for Continuous Query Notification
at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.VerifyExecution(OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.VerifyExecution(OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteNonQuery(String commandText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConnectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, Int64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionParamColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean isFromEF)
at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

also i get this message when i use joins in the following syntax:

```
select   
     t1.Col1,  
     t1.Col2,  
     t2.Col1  
from Table1 t1  
inner join Table2 t2 on (t2.FK_T1_ID = t1.ID)
```

with the following syntax, it works fine

```
select   
     t1.Col1,  
     t1.Col2,  
     t2.Col1  
from Table1 t1, Table2 t2  
where t2.FK_T1_ID = t1.ID
```

My question is, is there a list of supported query types? (queries on tables, views, materialized views, dblinks, joins... and so on)

I use the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll version 4.121.2.0

Supports the Oracle.DataAccess.dll more types as the Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.dll?